# Migration error Duplicate entry

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.3, migration

I am getting below error while I am Migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

```
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order. Fields: dailydeals,rpdiscount_amount,base_rpdiscount_amount,tax_rpdiscount_amount,base_tax_rpdiscount_amount
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote. Fields: customer_tipopessoa,customer_ie
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_address. Fields: rpdiscount_amount,base_rpdiscount_amount,tax_rpdiscount_amount,base_tax_rpdiscount_amount
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Inventory Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:39][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:42][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:43][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:56:43][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:57:05][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-29 09:57:05][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started
83% [=======================>----] Remaining Time: 22 mins
In Mysql.php line 182:
                                                                                                    
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '203650' for key 'PRIMARY'  
                                                                                                    

migrate:data [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--] <config>
```

What is the solution ?

Comment: The destination database needs to be fresh install magento2 database. If it has been changed, it needs to be cleaned. After you can run `bin/magento migrate:data -ra <xml_file_path> -vvv`

Comment: Thanks @yvzyldrm. I always try with fresh database.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore database entities, add the `<ignore>` tag to an entity in the `map.xml` file, like this:

**For Example :-**

```
<source>
    <field_rules>
            <ignore>
                <field>sales_flat_order.dailydeals</field>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <field>sales_flat_order.rpdiscount_amount</field>
            </ignore>
    </field_rules>
</source>
```

Your ignore follow this direction `<source> -> <field_rules> -> <field_rules> -> <field><EXTENSION_TABLE>.<EXTENSION_FIELD></field>`

**NOTE:-** i have in answer add only for Example two filed ignore.So you are all <EXTENSION_TABLE>  ignore your fileds.

Your get more information check this link :-

**https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033020451**

Hope this help your.

Thanks ...

Comment: Thanks  @Mohit Patel. May be you missed the error. Please see the error here https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2vXR.png

Comment: first solve all ignore error. After not solve check this link - --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359120/integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-1-for-key-primary

Comment: i think this error related is above error this :- https://prnt.sc/t8lze3

Comment: Are you talking about this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7NRk.png

Comment: Yes, this error

Comment: What is the solution ?

Comment: check my answer this is solution